# Updating PHP session variable using jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know this question has been answered multiple times but I haven't been able to find one specifically to solve my problem.
I'm making a website where a user can sell their eBay items, using the eBay API (which is a bit of a pain!).  My problem is at the results' pagination: I need a way of updating a `$_SESSION` page number variable so that the page reloads and displays a different page of results. I'm doing this with AJAX, and it's my first time using it.

The process is the following:

1)User clicks on one of the pagination links on the bottom of the page (like what's at the bottom of your Google results), which I made into a form with a hidden field storing the next page number that updates accordingly when the user clicks.

2)Use AJAX to update said `$_SESSION` variable on an external page (without refreshing!)

3)Reload the page and display the appropriate page of results.

The problem seems to be between steps #2 and 3.  The bits of code I use:

**Set $_SESSION variable**

```
 <?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['pageNumber']))
  {
    $_SESSION['pageNumber'] = "1";
    echo("Session value NOT set, pageNumber = " . $_SESSION['pageNumber']);
  }
  else
  {
    echo("Session value SET, pageNumber = " . $_SESSION['pageNumber']);
  }
?>
```

**Pagination**

```
<form action="">
<div id="pagination" style="text-align:center; <?php if($totalPages == 1) echo('display:none;');?>">
  <?php
    global $totalPages;
    if(intval($_SESSION['pageNumber']) != 1)
    {
      print("<a href=\"\" onclick=\"updatePageNumber(-1);\">Previous Page</a>");
    }
    for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
    {
      print("<a href=\"\" onclick=\"updatePageNumber('$i');\">$i</a>");
      print("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    }
    if(intval($_SESSION['pageNumber']) != $totalPages)
    {
      print("<a href=\"\" onclick=\"updatePageNumber(0);\">Next Page</a>");
    }
  ?>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="nextPageNumber" id="nextPageNumber" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['pageNumber']);?>">
</form>
```

**Update Hidden Field and $_SESSION Value**

```
function updatePageNumber(newNumber)
{
  //Update hidden field
  if(newNumber == -1)
  {
    var num = document.getElementById('nextPageNumber').value;
    num--;
    document.getElementById('nextPageNumber').value = num;
  }
  else if(newNumber == 0)
  {
    var num = document.getElementById('nextPageNumber').value;
    num++;
    document.getElementById('nextPageNumber').value = num;
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('nextPageNumber').value = newNumber;
  }

  //Update $_SESSION value with AJAX
  var dataString = 'nextPageNumber='+ document.getElementById('nextPageNumber').value;  
  $.ajax(
  {  
    url: "scripts/updatePageNumber.php", 
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(text)
    {
      alert("Done! Response: " + text);
    }

});
```

**And the PHP file**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['nextPageNumber']))
{
    session_start();
    die("Made it this far!");
    $nextPageNumber = $_POST['nextPageNumber'];
    $_SESSION['pageNumber'] = $nextPageNumber;
    echo $nextPageNumber;
}
?>
```

**Note:** I don't get to the PHP file's `die()` method, nor the alert with the AJAX's success (by the way, is that how to properly get the response text?)

I'd greatly appreciate any help at all, I've been stuck at this for quite a long time now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax call doesnt have `nextPageNumber` in its data, so it isn't seen by your PHP script (not in $_POST array) your test for it fails.

(As a general comment, your question involves too many working parts that makes it not a good fit for a site like this, devoted to helping others with similar problems. Next time please isolate the very part of the code that is causing the problem. This is likely why you have no other answers yet - people are sick of getting downvoted when trying to help solve something so comprehensive.)

Comment: Great! How could I go about fixing that?  By the way, thanks for your response, I knew the question was getting really long but I wasn't 100% sure where the issue could be so I just put all possible parts.  Next time I guess I'll instead put parts of code as they're needed rather than all at once!

Comment: No idea at all? I've been trying about five different methods, including using `GET` instead of `POST`, but still no use.

Comment: Your dataString doesnt contain nextPageNumber. Try ```var dataString = {"nextPageNumber":$("#nextPageNumber").val()}```